# ExtJS - How to get component item value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a component as follow :

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    layout: 'hbox',
    id: 'article-level-container',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'top'
    },
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'LEVEL',
        name: 'artLevel',
        inputWidth: 216,
        margins: '0 5 5 0',
        allowBlank: false,
        fieldStyle: 'text-align: right; font-size: 13pt; background-color: #EAFFCC;'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'VALUE',
        name: 'artValue',
        inputWidth: 216,
        allowBlank: false,
        blankText: 'zorunlu alan, boş bırakılamaz',
        fieldStyle: 'text-align: right; font-size: 13pt; background-color: #EAFFCC;',
        listeners: {
            change: function(textfield, newValue, oldValue) {
                if (oldValue == 'undefined' || newValue == '') {
                    Ext.getCmp('btnArticleSave').disable();
                } else {
                    Ext.getCmp('btnArticleSave').enable();
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to get second item `fieldLabel` value ( in this case VALUE ).

- How can I get this field value outside the `onReady` function?
- How can I change this field label with new value ( I want to change fieldlabel with selected combobox value )

**UPDATE**
I tried the following :

```
var artField = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#articleValueField');
console.log(artField);
```

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A few ways but common is to use `Ext.ComponentQuery`:

Give your field an `itemId` in its config e.g. `itemId: 'theField'`:

```
 var field= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#theField')[0];
 field.setFieldLabel(valueFromCombo);
```

Add an on `change` listener to your combo, you can use up and down (which are also component queries)

```
listeners: {
  change: function(combo) {
    var form = combo.up('#form');
    var field = form.down('#theField');
    field.setFieldLabel(lookupValueFromCombo);
  }
}
```

Remember any config settings in ext js will get a setter and getter, thus `fieldLabel` has `getFieldLabel()` & `setFieldLabel(s)` methods.

**edit**
above is only with ext js 4.1+
with ext js 4.0+ you can do:

```
field.labelEl.update('New Label');
```

Comment: Nothing more to say. +1

Comment: I think I am doing wrong something. When tried to get field with `ComponentQuery` I can see values of the field in the console. But neither `getFieldLabel` nor `setFieldLabel` doesn't work. I am getting 'setFieldLabel' is not a function error! Do you have any idea?

Comment: dear @sra have you got any idea as well?

Comment: the class name is `Ext.form.field.Text`

Comment: holly shit! if I add index number, the public functions appear on the variable. `artField[0].setFieldLabel('Text');` works well. I don't understand the reason of the index number. Do you know?

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir You need to access the result via a index

Comment: yes `ComponentQuery.query` returns an array, thanks for reminding :S

Comment: @sra and jenson, thank you so much guys, have a good work for both.

Answer (score 1):

to get the combobox selected item outside the combo listener

```
yourComboboxName.on('change', function (combo, record, index) {

            alert(record);  // to get the selected item

            console.log(record);  // to get the selected item

        });
```